# SSRS Format string to date time DD MMM YYYY HH MM

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Display in reporting services text box - data is grouped.
Best way to format grouped data 20170518110610 to `DD MMM YYYY HH MM`?

I.e.

```
18 May 2017 11:06
```

Tried Text box properties - number - custom format - dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm the result is the same **20170518110610**

Comment: Format 20170517 as 18 May 2017?

Comment: sorry yes format data 20170518110610 to DD MMM YYYY HH MM

Comment: There are a format property, what's the problem?

Comment: You should be able to do this using the SSRS interface. Just go to the properties of that text box and format it.

Comment: sorry data is grouped

Comment: What is datatype of `20170518110610`?

Comment: Datatype is Varchar

Answer (score 3):

You have problems because `20170518110610` is a `varchar`. You need to convert it to date before format it.

Possible solutions:

1) Return a `datetime` not `varchar` from datasource (preferred)

2) Parse value in SSRS then format value:

```
=Format(DateTime.ParseExact("20170518110610", "yyyyMMddHHmmss", Nothing), "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm")
```